# How To Style Button's Hover And Click Foreground?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, styles, hover

I am new to `Styles` and not sure on the best way to create a `Button` style to change the `Foreground` of `IsMouseOver` and `IsPressed`. I used a `Border` for a template because it has a `CornerRadius` and background and border properties. But `Border` does not have a `Foreground` property. Using `Button` as the template doesn't work well since the default look isn't being overridden.

What is a better way to style a `Button` template with `Foreground` behavior? Maybe using a label inside the border?

Here is the App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButton">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="34"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Name="shortcutbutton"  
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="Black"
                    Background="Gray">
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="2" 
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="shortcutbutton" Property="Background" Value="#FFDADADA" />
                            <Setter TargetName="shortcutbutton" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#EEEEEE" />
                            <!--<Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />-->
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="shortcutbutton" Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
                            <Setter TargetName="shortcutbutton" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                            <!--<Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />-->
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

And the xaml:

```
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100">
        <Button Content="Button" Height="41" Style="{DynamicResource MyButton}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is set attached property of `TextElement` on the `Border` and like that every text element within your `Border` will be of that colour:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
       <Setter TargetName="shortcutbutton" Property="Background" Value="#FFDADADA" />
       <Setter TargetName="shortcutbutton" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#EEEEEE" />
       <Setter TargetName="shortcutbutton" Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="White"/>
   </Trigger>
   ...
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to move your Triggers from the ControlTemplate to the Style. Something like  this:

```
        <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="34"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Name="shortcutbutton"  
                BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                Background="Gray">
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="2" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                              RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFDADADA" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Thanks. This method seems to work as well. I found dkozl's method to be slightly simpler.